# MongoDB - text search in multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have read through the mongodb documentation and learned that you can do a full-text search like this:

```
db.quotes.runCommand( "text", { search: "tomorrow largo" } )
```

But how can you search for two independent text indices for two separate conditions in the same collection?

Comment: You can only have one text index per collection, but the text index can include multiple fields. Could you give a more concrete example?

Comment: Thanks. That answers my question as what I'm trying to achieve cannot be done if there aren't multiple text indexes per collection.